# How to create lua coroutines using the lua c api?

Tags: c, api, lua

How to create lua coroutines using lua c api and expose it to lua?

I am writing a library in c for lua, And I was wondering how to implement lua coroutine using lua c api. I basically want to implement something like the following, where module is written in c programming language.

```lua
module = require("mymodule")

coroutine.resume(module.coroutine_function, ...)
```

Comment: In C you create a new thread with `lua_newthread` and then resume any function in it. See [lcorolib.c](https://www.lua.org/source/5.4/lcorolib.c.html) in the Lua sources.

Comment: @lhf I have gone through [lcorolib.c](https://www.lua.org/source/5.4/lcorolib.c.html) but I still have some problems. My coroutine function looks like this ```
int coroutine(lua_State* L)
{
 lua_pushfstring(L, "Wonderfull");
 return lua_yield(L, 1);
}```
And resuming the function more than once does not return the string "wonderfull". I want the coroutine to keep yielding the string "Wonderfull". Something like this 
```
function iter()
    while true do
        coroutine.yield("Wonderfull")
    end
end```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is C code yields the string "Wonderfull" 4 times. And returns the string "End" before terminating the coroutine.

```c
static int kfunction(lua_State* L, int status, lua_KContext ctx)
{
    static int x = 0;
    
    if (x < 3)
    {
        x++;
        lua_pushfstring(L, "Wonderfull");
        return lua_yieldk(L, 1, 0, kfunction);
    }
    lua_pushfstring(L, "End");
    return 1;
}

static int iter(lua_State* L)
{
    lua_pushfstring(L, "Wonderfull");
    return lua_yieldk(L, 1, 0, kfunction);
}


int luaopen_module(lua_State* L) {
    // initial function which is called when require("module") is run

    lua_State* n = lua_newthread(L);
    lua_setglobal(L, "coroutine_function");

    lua_pushcfunction(n, iter);

    return 0;
}
```

Using the C module in Lua:

```lua
require("module")

print(coroutine.resume(coroutine_function))  -- true  Wonderfull
print(coroutine.resume(coroutine_function))  -- true  Wonderfull
print(coroutine.resume(coroutine_function))  -- true  Wonderfull
print(coroutine.resume(coroutine_function))  -- true  Wonderfull
print(coroutine.resume(coroutine_function))  -- true  End
print(coroutine.resume(coroutine_function))  -- false cannot resume dead coroutine
```

`int iter(lua_State* L)` is called when `coroutine.resume` is called for the first time. The subsequent calls are to `int kfunction(lua_State* L, int status, lua_KContext ctx)`.

4th argument to `lua_yieldk` can be thorugh as the next function Lua should call to get the next yield or return value.

Documentation: [Handling Yields in C](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#4.5)